# Do you get referrer data from HTTPS > HTTP > 301 Redirect > HTTPS site?

Tags: google-analytics, 301-redirect, https

Referrer data is lost when a HTTPS site links to a HTTP site.

If you implement a 301 rediect from your HTTP site to your HTTPS site do you get referrer data?

```
Referring Site  |          Your Site 
      HTTPS    >>>   HTTP  >>> 301 >>> HTTPS
```

or do you have to make sure the source HTTPS site links directly to your HTTPS site?

```
Referring Site  |  Your Site 
      HTTPS    >>>   HTTPS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you bounce at all to HTTP, even in a 301 case, you will lose the header.  The 301 is handled by the browser (or other client) so the protocol transition will happen there.

Some possible workaround ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916848/implement-http-to-https-redirect-preserving-google-analytics-referrer